# Automate the def function in pandas for correlation

Tags: python, statistics, pandas

```py
def correlations(group):
    # Remove columns
    group = (
        group.reset_index()
        .drop(columns=["RNA1_Approved_Symbol"], level=0)
        .set_index("RNA1_ID")
    )
    # compute correlations
    correlation = group.T.corr()

    # rename pair column
    correlation = correlation.reset_index().rename(
        columns={"RNA1_ID": "RNA1_ID_new"}
    )

    # Remove NAs
    corr_result = (
        correlation.melt(value_name="Correlation", id_vars=["RNA1_ID_new"])
        .set_index(["RNA1_ID", "RNA1_ID_new"])
        .dropna()
    )
    return corr_result


def correlation_1(data):
    ## Create Pivot table
    pivot_library = data.pivot(
        index=["RNA1_Approved_Symbol", "RNA1_ID"], columns=["RNA2_ID"]
    )

    # Measure correlations between four id's
    return (
        pivot_library.groupby("RNA1_Approved_Symbol")
        .apply(correlations)
        .reset_index()
        .dropna()
    )
```

I am using the above function to calculate the correlation

```py
data = df1
correlations = correlation_1(df1)
```

I want to automate the above function when I am using different data frame where there is `RNA2_Approved_Symbol` instead of `RNA1_Approved_Symbol` and `RNA2_ID` instead of `RNA1_ID`. Like using index 1 and index 2.

Comment: Hi @Riya, pretty sure I could solve this. Could you supply a test data set for your new dataframe please? Actually, I think I get the question and there's no need of a dataset. Hope to have a response end of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question is to generalise the column names to permit a function to accept dataframes where you don't have the same column name, or it's different from the previous dataframe column names. Here the column could be called `RNA1_Approved_Symbol` or `RNA2_Approved_Symbol` in addition a different column could be called `RNA2_ID` or `RNA_ID`. No problem providing the column order is identical for the columns in question. If the orders are not identical see the code below the `----` to correct that.

If the order is identical the simple answer is `df.columns[i]`. Thus it's obtaining the column name on its position within the dataframe (`columns` command), where `i` is the column location.

Example, to rename `RNA1_ID` to `RNA1_ID_new`, or `RNA2_ID` to `RNA2_ID_new`

```
import re

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"perch": [5,6,7], "RNA1_ID": [1,2,4], "roach": [30,42,51]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"perch": [5,6,7], "RNA2_ID": [1,2,4], "roach": [30,42,51]})

def renamecolumn(df):
    myname = df.columns[1]
    newname = re.sub(r'$','_new', myname)
    df = df.rename(columns={myname: newname})
    return df

print (renamecolumn(df1))
print (renamecolumn(df2))
```

Output,

| - | perch | RNA1_ID_new | roach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 42 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 | 51 |

| - | perch | RNA2_ID_new | roach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 42 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 | 51 |

I noted there was a fair number of `set_index` commands so the earlier the column name can be trapped inside a variable the better, because `set_index` will change the column order.

---

Alternatively, the columns can be re-arranged to be in a given order if the original order between `df1` and `df2` is different. Here I'll move the column to the front.

```
mycols = df1.columns.tolist()
mycols = mycols[-2:] + mycols[:-2]
df1 = df1[mycols]
print (df1)
```

| - | RNA1_ID | roach | perch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 30 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 42 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 51 | 7 |

Thus `RNA1_ID` has been moved from the second to the first column. If `df2` was in the last column repeat as above use `-1` instead of `-2` and both columns will now be at the start of the dataframe. Modify the core dataframe generalisation renaming accordingly, viz.

```
myname = df.columns[0]
```

... sorted.