# Math on Pandas Columns

Tags: python, phylogenetics, phylogeny, sequence-analysis, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that reads in a PAF file from minimap2. What I would like to do is take the first 5 columns of the data from to create a BED file.

I used this to extract the first 5 columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(tag1_paf, delimiter = "\t")
#print(df[4])

specific_columns=df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]]
print(specific_columns)
```

Which outputs this:

```
read1  47215  20591  21087 +
read2  14111  3478   3973  +
read3  30861  21367  21855 +
read4  4647   767    1257  -
read5  11706  9569   9990  +
```

But now I want to do math on the third and fourth columns depending on the strand its on. For example, if column 5 = "+" add 1000 to the third column.

I can't figure it out on my own - I've tried looking it up and using the series add/sub methods from pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) but I'm still confused.

If anyone can help that would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The vectorised solution (fast) is,

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = '/pathtodir/test/bioinfo.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delimiter=" ", header=None)

df.loc[df[4] == "+", 'new2'] = df[2] + 1000
df.loc[df[4] == "-", 'new2'] = df[2]
df = df.drop([2], axis=1)
df = df[[0,1,'new2',3,4]]
print (df)
```

| - | 0 | 1 | new2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | read1 | 47215 | 21591.0 | 21087 | + |
| 1 | read2 | 14111 | 4478.0 | 3973 | + |
| 2 | read3 | 30861 | 22367.0 | 21855 | + |
| 3 | read4 | 4647 | 767.0 | 1257 | - |
| 4 | read5 | 11706 | 10569.0 | 9990 | + |

An alternative method to re-order the columns then the answer is [Automate the def function in pandas for correlation](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20605/automate-the-def-function-in-pandas-for-correlation)

Original data

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | read1 | 47215 | 20591 | 21087 | + |
| 1 | read2 | 14111 | 3478 | 3973 | + |
| 2 | read3 | 30861 | 21367 | 21855 | + |
| 3 | read4 | 4647 | 767 | 1257 | - |
| 4 | read5 | 11706 | 9569 | 9990 | + |

---

Final solution

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delimiter=" ", header=None)
df.loc[df[4] == "+", 'new2'] = df[2] + 1000
df.loc[df[4] == "-", 'new2'] = df[2] - 1000
df.loc[df['new2'] < 0, 'new2'] = 1
df = df.drop([2], axis=1)
df = df[[0,1,'new2',3,4]]
print (df)
```

| - | 0 | 1 | new2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | read1 | 47215 | 21591.0 | 21087 | + |
| 1 | read2 | 14111 | 4478.0 | 3973 | + |
| 2 | read3 | 30861 | 22367.0 | 21855 | + |
| 3 | read4 | 4647 | 1.0 | 1257 | - |
| 4 | read5 | 11706 | 10569.0 | 9990 | + |

... worked too

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Quick follow up question -  I was able to add in parameters where if df[4] = "-" then subtract 1000 from df[2] but if there is an instance where the value becomes negative I would just like to make it equal 1. Is there a quick way to add that into this as well? I don't wanna mess around with if statements if it's going to yell at me for formatting

Comment: @rimo modified above below the `----`. Any value that is negative will be changed to 1

Comment: The `-1000` is now included.